# Loading an Excel file (with variable # of columns) into database using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I need to do a routine import of an Excel file.  The problem is the columns of the Excel is not fixed.  For example one month if can be:

```
first_name   last_name   question_are_you_happy     question_how_old_are_you
John         Smith       no                         32
Jane         Doe         yes                        11
```

Next month it can be

```
first_name   last_name   question_favorite_color    
John         Smith       blue                       
Jane         Doe         red
```

Every Excel will have common columns such as first_name and last_name, however the other "question" column can be different.  My goal is to load the data into a database table such that it looks like:

```
first_name   last_name   question           answer
John         Smith       are_you_happy      no
John         Smith       how_old_are_you    32
John         Smith       favorite_color     blue
Jane         Doe         are_you_happy      yes 
Jane         Doe         how_old_are_you    11
Jane         Doe         favorite_color     red
```

I know in SSIS there is an unpivot transformation, however it seems that it cannot work with variable amount of columns?  The problem is my source has different # of column with different name.

Comment: Do you know all of the possible column names?

Comment: Is there a maximum number (N) of columns possible? Where I am getting at is.. you can try loading the entire data including the header row into a staging table with columns like - Column1, Column2..., ColumnN. Thus you would have the header information as well in the table and you can use TSQL or Script to extract the header data and do accordingly.

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3002/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-dynamically-normalize-output/ will lead you in the right direction